# Optimization of AutoCompleteTextView initialization

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm a newcomer to Android world.
I'm facing an performance problem in my app under development.

I've one activity with one `AutoCompleteTextView`. I'm initializing it on `onCreate()` of activity with an `adapter` like below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, keywords);
    final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `"keywords"` is an `String[]` which I'm reading from `json` file containing a almost 3000 entries every time on `onCreate()`. At the same time, I get values against "keyword" and adding to a `HashMap`

Because of this, loading time of this activity is slowing down.

By what means I can reduce:

1. Reading `json` file only one time
2. Initialize `adapter` one time
3. So next time onward I can load the activity faster [First time I can show some "loading..." dialog]

Comment: Where is that json file? Local or on server?

Comment: Local. It is from assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

1. Parse json in a background thread and put a loading bar.
2. Once strings are parsed and displayed, you save them via in an instance(onSavedInstanceState). As long as activity is not destroyed displaying them will be faster.
3. Save strings in sharedpreferences or SQlite DB(this option depends on app, like what strings are you displaying).